# Redirect to referer ignores user entries

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to display error messages (Business logic) when then user enters invalid data.

I have a template with a couple of fields.  Field values are sent as query parameters.

In my Action, I check the fields and, whenever I find an error, I redirect to the same page adding the error message:

```
request.headers.get(REFERER).getOrElse("/main").flashing("error" -> "Some error")
```

The message is displayed, but all the entries that the user made are gone!  This is annoying, the user would need to enter all the data again.

I update the objects that are displayed in the corresponding template, but this new information is not shown.

I know that I could try working with forms, but in this case the fields are dynamically generated.

Is there a way to redirect to the same page, updated with the dava given by the user, and show an error message?

Comment: I suppose you forgot some method in your snippet (Redirect(.....).flashing())

Comment: What do you extacly mean, Julien? My snippet is only used whenever I find an error.  I also tried OK(...).flashing("error" -> "Some error").  In this case the fields are updated, but the message is not displayed (flash does work only with Redirect, it seems silly that Ok has also a flasing method).

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting to same URL is NOT equal to rendering form with the same data. When you're performing redirect it's the same as user just went to your form from the outside.

Check the docs of forms in section [Handling binding failure](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaForms)

Comment: I already stated that I am not using a Play form, and I can not use a form because the fields are dynamically generated.  In my template I am using just plain scala objects.  These objects have some values that are displayed.  After an error the same values are displayed, the user input is ignored.  This is my problem.